# how to make asynchronous API calls nested with ensure_future and gather in Python Asyncio?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

Im trying to make asynchronous API calls nested with asyncio using ensure_future() and gather().

I have tried two methods of getting this to work.
First of all the API is written with aiohttp and works fine.
I have tried it with two methods (here named get_rows_working() and get_rows_not_working()). One is working and one is not.

A single row always does its API calls in parallel to increase speed.
Now what I'm trying to do is getting all rows pulled in parallel aswell.

```py
async def get_single_row(api):
    tasks = []
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(api.get_some_data())
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(api.get_some_data2())
    resp = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    data = resp[0]
    data2 = resp[1]


    extra_data = data['some_key']
    extra_data2 = data2['some_key2']
    return (extra_data, extra_data2)

async def get_rows_working(rows):
    data = []
    for r in rows:
        api = API(r)
        data.append(await get_single_row(api))
    return data

async def get_rows_not_working(rows):
    tasks = []
    for r in rows:
        api = API(r)
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_single_row(api)))
    data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return data


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get_rows_working())
loop.run_until_complete(get_rows_not_working())
```

What happens if you start nesting these?
Because im starting to get KeyErrors on these lines (which I dont have with get_rows_working()):

```py
extra_data = data['some_key']
extra_data2 = data2['some_key2']
```

Which makes me believe the internal order of operations gets all wonky because of nesting these.
Im not sure how to describe it better, sorry.

Is this even to correct way to achieve this?
Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `KeyError` exceptions are related to the way your code is structured.

In order to reproduce your results, I mocked your API calls using `asyncio.sleep()`:

```py
import asyncio

class API:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

    async def get_some_data(self, i):
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        return {'key_{}'.format(i) : 'Data_{}___Row_{}'.format(i, self.r)}

async def get_single_row(api):
    tasks = []
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(api.get_some_data(0)))
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(api.get_some_data(1)))

    resp = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    data_0 = resp[0]
    data_1 = resp[1]

    extra_data_0 = data_0['key_0']
    extra_data_1 = data_1['key_1']
    return (extra_data_0, extra_data_1)

async def get_rows_working(rows):
    data = []
    for r in rows:
        api = API(r)
        data.append(await get_single_row(api))
    return data

async def get_rows_not_working(rows):
    tasks = []
    for r in rows:
        api = API(r)
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_single_row(api)))
    data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return data
```

Then added a timer, and run both functions to understand what happens:

```py
import time
class Timer:    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.perf_counter()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
rows = range(10)

with Timer() as t:
    res = loop.run_until_complete(get_rows_working(rows))
    print("get_rows_working() result : {}".format(res))
print('get_rows_working() API call took %.03f sec.\n' % t.interval)

with Timer() as t:
    res = loop.run_until_complete(get_rows_not_working(rows))
    print("get_rows_not_working() result : {}".format(res))
print('get_rows_not_working() API call took %.03f sec.' % t.interval)
```

**Output:**

```
get_rows_working() result : [('Data_0___Row_0', 'Data_1___Row_0'), ('Data_0___Row_1', 'Data_1___Row_1'), ('Data_0___Row_2', 'Data_1___Row_2'), ('Data_0___Row_3', 'Data_1___Row_3'), ('Data_0___Row_4', 'Data_1___Row_4'), ('Data_0___Row_5', 'Data_1___Row_5'), ('Data_0___Row_6', 'Data_1___Row_6'), ('Data_0___Row_7', 'Data_1___Row_7'), ('Data_0___Row_8', 'Data_1___Row_8'), ('Data_0___Row_9', 'Data_1___Row_9')]
get_rows_working() API call took 30.034 sec.

get_rows_not_working() result : [('Data_0___Row_0', 'Data_1___Row_0'), ('Data_0___Row_1', 'Data_1___Row_1'), ('Data_0___Row_2', 'Data_1___Row_2'), ('Data_0___Row_3', 'Data_1___Row_3'), ('Data_0___Row_4', 'Data_1___Row_4'), ('Data_0___Row_5', 'Data_1___Row_5'), ('Data_0___Row_6', 'Data_1___Row_6'), ('Data_0___Row_7', 'Data_1___Row_7'), ('Data_0___Row_8', 'Data_1___Row_8'), ('Data_0___Row_9', 'Data_1___Row_9')]
get_rows_not_working() API call took 3.008 sec.
```

Which means that the second function `get_rows_not_working()` actually works as expected and calls the API concurrently.

Is it possible that you are getting `KeyError` exceptions because the API returns empty data when you exceed the request rate limit? For example, if the API is implemented as:

```py
MAX_CONCUR_ROWS = 5
class API:
    connections = 0
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

    async def get_some_data(self, i):
        API.connections += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        if API.connections > MAX_CONCUR_ROWS * 2:
            res = {}
        else:
            res = {'key_{}'.format(i) : 'Data_{}___Row_{}'.format(i, self.r)}
        API.connections -= 1
        return res
```

Then `get_rows_not_working()` would return `KeyError: 'key_0'`, while `get_rows_working()` works fine.

If that's the case, then you would want to throttle your requests, by batching them, or using [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) :

```py
async def get_single_row(api, semaphore):
    # using tasks instead of coroutines won't work because asyncio.ensure_future() starts the coroutine, so the semaphore won't have any effect.
    coros = []
    coros.append(api.get_some_data(0))
    coros.append(api.get_some_data(1))

    async with semaphore:
        resp = await asyncio.gather(*coros)
    data_0 = resp[0]
    data_1 = resp[1]

    extra_data_0 = data_0['key_0']
    extra_data_1 = data_1['key_1']
    return (extra_data_0, extra_data_1)

async def get_rows_not_working(rows):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(MAX_CONCUR_ROWS)
    tasks = []
    for r in rows:
        api = API(r)
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_single_row_coros(api, semaphore)))
    data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return data
```

The above code doesn't perform more than 5 concurrent calls at a time and returns the expected output (notice the it takes 6 sec. now instead of 3):

```
get_rows_not_working() result : [('Data_0___Row_0', 'Data_1___Row_0'), ('Data_0___Row_1', 'Data_1___Row_1'), ('Data_0___Row_2', 'Data_1___Row_2'), ('Data_0___Row_3', 'Data_1___Row_3'), ('Data_0___Row_4', 'Data_1___Row_4'), ('Data_0___Row_5', 'Data_1___Row_5'), ('Data_0___Row_6', 'Data_1___Row_6'), ('Data_0___Row_7', 'Data_1___Row_7'), ('Data_0___Row_8', 'Data_1___Row_8'), ('Data_0___Row_9', 'Data_1___Row_9')]
get_rows_not_working() API call took 6.013 sec.
```

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look!